# PHP error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working on web app that require a login page, everything work fine but i noticed that when a user try to connect and his password contain caracter he can't and an ugly error appear says `FATAL ERROR:Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object`.
here is my code:

```
$password=$_GET["password"];
$req="SELECT * FROM `enseignant` WHERE ens_cin=$login AND ens_pass=$password";
$res=$idconnex->query($req);
if($res->rowCount() > 0)
    {echo 'SUCCESS CONNECT';}
else
    {echo 'FAIL CONNECT';}
```

when i tried to add `!empty($result)` in `if()` ,thing goes worst.. it conseder all those how has caracteres in thier pass as not signed in user!! but no error appear..
thanks for help and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: try with if($res > 0{//your same code}. or if($res){//your same code}

Comment: Read the docs *`"Returns FALSE on failure, object on success ..."`*

Comment: And you seem to be wide open to SQL injection ?

Comment: let's drop the SQL injection subject away if it is not related with the error cause i will handel it after everything goes right..

Comment: @MalekBoubakri we'd like to drop that, but you'd be amazed as to some who downvote answers because they haven't informed the user of potential dangers.

Comment: @Fred -ii thank you, you'r right but the error is in the top of problems list right now..

Comment: You're welcome Malek. Have you consulted my answer that I have given below that I posted earlier?

Comment: i will be glad if you check the new problem i rewrite up in the post,

Comment: No, I will not. Post a new question. I did a rollback to your original post. That's not how things are done around here on Stack.

Comment: ok i will post another question :(
sorry if i done something not ethical but i'm new here in this forum as you see.. 
thanks for re answer the new one.. and i re-accept your answer by the way!

Comment: here is the new one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721963/warning-pdoexec-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're more than likely dealing with strings here, so the variables in your values need to be quoted.

```
WHERE ens_cin='$login' AND ens_pass='$password'";
```

Plus, just using PDO on its own, doesn't mean you're safe against SQL injection.

- [**Use PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

***An insight:***

Make sure that you are indeed connecting through PDO and not `mysqli_`. I see these types of questions often.

If that is the case, those different MySQL APIs do not intermix with each other.

Now this:

```
$password=$_GET["password"];
```

Passing a password through a GET isn't safe neither; you don't know who may be "listening in". You should be using POST. I hope also that you are using a hash and not plain text for password storage.

Sidenote: Make sure you're indeed using GET and not mixed up with POST, should this be coming from an HTML form.

---

> *"but no error appear"*

You are probably not checking for errors.

Add `$idconnex->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: should i check out if i'm connecting through PDO and not mysqli_ aven now??
and how can i check it out!!! 
and thank's again...

Comment: @MalekBoubakri You're welcome. You are connecting with PDO, correct? I had to mention that in my answer, because I see that often, and it sometimes relates to that.

Comment: @MalekBoubakri I have made an edit in my answer concerning error checking.

Comment: @MalekBoubakri Am glad you like Malek :)

Comment: i will be glad if you recheck the new problem i rewrite up in the post :(

Comment: @MalekBoubakri You can't do that. You accepted my answer for the original question and reposted after. You have to re-accept mine and post a new question. This isn't ethical at all.

Comment: ok i will post another question :( sorry if i done something not ethical but i'm new here in this forum as you see.. thanks for re answer the new one.. and i re-accept your answer by the way!

Comment: here is the new one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721963/warning-pdoexec-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string

Answer (score 0):

The `query()` function returned something that is not an object.

You should **always** check for errors.

```
$res = $idconnex->query($req);
if ( ! $res) {
    echo 'This is not an object:<br>';
    var_dump($res);
    die;
}
```

You should also always [read the manual](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) when you run into problems:

> **Return Values**
>
> PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, ***or FALSE on failure***.

Answer (score 0):

It's not safe to pass parameters to a query like the way you did. The problem you encountered might be caused by some unsafe characters. You might need to escape it.

Your implementation is wide open to SQL Injection.
Use prepared statement instead. It's safer and will save you from problems such as this.

And one more thing, I notice that you are trying to search `$_GET['password']` inside your database directly. Where I can conclude that you store the password inside your database without any hashing or encryption. You might want to reconsider that.

Comment: please, let's drop the SQL injection subject away if it is not related with the error cause i will handel it after everything goes right..

Comment: Ok, maybe you can put the variable in single quotes `ens_pass='$password'` or `$req="SELECT * FROM \`enseignant\` WHERE ens_cin=$login AND ens_pass='".$password."'";`

Comment: thank and i have some trouble when i convert to to PDO and use prepared quary here is new problem please check it !! 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721963/warning-pdoexec-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string/29722011#29722011