# Warning: PDO::exec() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working on web app that require a login page, everything work until I try to convert to PDO and use prepared query here is my code:

```
$req=$idconnex->prepare("SELECT * FROM `enseignant` WHERE ens_cin=:cin AND ens_pass=:pass");
$req->bindParam(':cin',$_GET["login"]);
$req->bindParam(':pass',$_GET["password"]);
$res=$idconnex->exec($req);
if(!empty($res) AND $res->rowCount==1)          
    {echo 'SUCCESS';}
else
    {echo 'FAIL';}
```

A warning appearsy:

> Warning: PDO::exec() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in...

and it return FAIL as result even I insert correct param!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to jeroen's answer

```
$status = $req->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($status)          
{echo 'SUCCESS';}
else
{echo 'FAIL';}
```

The `$req->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` was actually asking for the result of the query. You can see what it contains by `var_dump($status)`.
It will return an associative array if a match is found or empty if no match is found.

PHP will evaluate non-empty variable as boolean `true` and empty,null,array with zero elements.. as boolean `false`.
`if($status)` is almost the same as `if($status == true)`. You can find this in the PHP manual.

Comment: Added some explanation to the answer. You do understand what jeroen wrote right ? If you want to put your code into production you will need to listen to his advice. :)

Answer (score 5):

When you prepare a statement, you need [`execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) instead of [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) and you need to use the object you set when you prepared it:

```
$req=$idconnex->prepare("SELECT * FROM `enseignant` WHERE ens_cin=:cin AND ens_pass=:pass");
$req->bindParam(':cin',$_GET["login"]);
$req->bindParam(':pass',$_GET["password"]);
$req->execute();
```

Also note that [`rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) is a method, not a property, and you cannot rely on its value when you use a `SELECT` query. See the manual page about [`rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) for more information.

Furthermore you should not use GET but POST when you send information like passwords and you should use a salted hash for your password, never a plain-text password. See [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords) for more details.

Comment: can i just replace all $_GET by $_POST and ask for the same result?